# How to convert an IP address to something 32 bit you can use as a dict key

Tags: python

If I have an IP address I can use it as a key in a dict as follows:

```
dict = {}
IP = "172.23.1.99"
dict[IP] = "pear"
```

However, if I have a lot of them this is very memory inefficient.

> How can I convert the IP to a 32 bit representation which I can still
>   use a key in a dict?

I could just convert the IP to an int. But python ints seem to consume 24 bytes each which is 192 bits so this **does not** solve my problem.

```
In [2]: sys.getsizeof(2**32-1)
Out[2]: 24
```

As I have  100s of millions of these IPs I would really like to represent them as 32 bits each.

From the comments it seems this may be hard in pure Python. I would be happy with a practical non-pure solution too (including using numpy or any other easily available package).

Comment: How many are 'a lot'? What 32 bit represenation to you want?

Comment: You can convert with this `first_part+2**8*second_part+2**16*third_part+2**32*fourth_part`. This will be 64-bit though

Comment: @caiohamamura Doesn't this give a python into which uses much more than 32 bits of storage to represent?

Comment: Yeah it would be 64-bit

Comment: @caiohamamura It's much worse than that. Please see the update.

Comment: To anyone voting to close, please see that converting to an int *does not* answer the question.

Comment: @eleanora Fair enough; retracted my close vote.

Comment: Processing 100s of millions might be better done in C++.

Comment: @eleanora: you cannot make "standalone" integers smaller in Python, that's the best you can get; objects in general are really fat in Python. If you have 100s of millions of IPs to keep in memory probably a Python dictionary is not a good idea anyway (you could use instead a custom, compact data structure exported by a C or C++ extension).

Comment: @caiohamamura: that's what I thought, but a numpy array is - well - an array, while she's trying to have an associative container. If this data structure is not updated often an easy solution could be a numpy array for the keys and a regular list for the values, sorted by keys. The lookup then could be O(log n) through binary search. But again, the exact choice of a "big" data structure is extremely dependent from the required access pattern.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I would be interested in a custom compacted data structure of the sort you suggest.

Comment: @eleanora: then you should explain the access pattern you require.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I simply need to be able to look up the value associated with any IP address. Your log time solution sounds interesting if we can't do any better.

Comment: Would   'raw = socket.inet_aton(IP)' work so that 'raw' could be used as a key?

Comment: @eleanora: keep in mind that my solution is ok if you *first* provide all data, *then* run the sort and *then* you do the lookup; adding stuff in the already set-up structure is O(n) (you have to shift everything around). If it's fine, I'll try to put it together in an answer.

Comment: @eleanora: it's not like integers in particular are "fat", it's that *all* objects in Python are fat. Every "standalone" object in CPython/64 bit has a pointer to its type (8 bytes) and a reference count (8 byte), so it's 16 bytes *minimum* for everything (that's the price to pay to have the type on the value instead of on the variable, plus the reference counting); then, any kind of payload you may add requires *at least* other 8 bytes to keep stuff aligned, so 24 bytes is the minimum you can get on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

Given the number of entries you intend to store, I suggest you use SQLite. It's both easy and probably efficient enough. In fact, it has the nice property that for every record it uses only as much space as necessary. For an IP address that is between 1 and 5 bytes depending on the IP address (so on average, 3 bytes).

Here's an example:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
import sqlite3

# Create an in-memory database.*
db_connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE ip_address_associations (
        ip_address INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        value TEXT
    )
''')

# Store the value for an IP address
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ip_address_associations VALUES (?, ?)', 
    (int(ip_address('172.23.1.99')), 'pear')
)

# Retrieve the value for an IP address
row = cursor.execute(
    'SELECT value FROM ip_address_associations WHERE ip_address = ?', 
    (int(ip_address('172.23.1.99')),)
).fetchone()
if row:
    value = row[0]
    print(value)
else:
    print('No results found.')
```

*Although I don't know exactly what your application is about, I highly suspect that there's no need to keep the whole database in memory all the time. You can save greatly on memory usage while not losing too much in access time by using a (temporary) file and relying on file caching. Replace `':memory:'` by `''` for a temporary file, or by a filename for a persistent one.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#module-ipaddress)  module:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
int(ip_address('172.23.1.99'))
```

output:

```
2887188835
```

and back:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
str(ip_address(2887188835))
```

output:

```
'172.23.1.99'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question sadly.